# the correct way to register core extensions to cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

The main repository already contains examples for extensions of layout/renderer, but I was not able to find a best-practice example for how to extend the core. Looking at the core components themselves, the following convention seems to work; but was wondering if it is against the best practices to do this (let's say, this is for `cytoscape.core.dumy.js`):

```
;(function($$){

    $$.fn.core({
        dummy: function(options) {
            var cy = this;
            // Do something with cy...

            return this;
        }
    });

})( cytoscape );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same as for collections.  Just change 'collection' to 'core':

```
cytoscape('core', 'dummy', function(){
  var cy = this;
  // ...

  return this; // chainability
});
```

Comment: And NB that the syntax you used in your example above is indeed against best practice.